# OpenLayers Large static image does not appear in the mobile browser

Tags: javascript, image, mobile, static, openlayers

I am using the code below OpenLayers to view a static image with the following dimensions 43000 px x 4000px, 10mb. In the browser on the computer the image appears normally, but the mobile browser does not appear the image. Could you tell me what I should do to fix this problem.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sistema de Solicitação de Acesso (SSA) - Alternativo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js? 
features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL">
</script>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/build/ol.js"></script>
<style>
.map {
width: auto;
height: 500px;
border: 5px outset black;
border-radius: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>

<script>
var extent = [0, 0, 50000, 1900];
var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
code: 'xkcd-image',
units: 'pixels',
extent: extent
});
var map = new ol.Map({layers: [
new ol.layer.Image({
source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
attributions: 'Criado por: Givanildo Silva de Amorim',
url: 'https://i.ibb.co/GHCdx84/Linhas-7-8-9-10-11-12-13.png',
projection: projection,     
imageExtent: extent
})
})
],
target: 'map',
view: new ol.View({
projection: projection,
center: [1600, 900],
zoom: 7,
maxZoom: 14
})
});
</script>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: It works in Chrome, but not Firefox.  Is there a reason you aren't using the latest version (6.4.3)?

Comment: You are hitting browser limits on canvas usage.  A 6400 x 12000 px image will cause similar problems in OpenLayers 6 (with Chrome on Windows PC).  If you need such a high resolution image you should cut it into tiles, otherwise reduce the image size.